# Хочу подключить react через cdn. Не работает. В чём проблема?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cdn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>React!</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
            <script type="text/babel">
                class Hello extends React.Component{render() {return <p>Hello!</p>}}
                ReaсtDOM.render(<Hello/>,document.querySelector("#container"));
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Подробнее.](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx)

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  class Hello extends React.Component{
      render() {
          return <p>Hello!</p>
      }
  }; 
  ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.querySelector('#container') );
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ссылки cdn у меня не рабочие были